# Symfony 3, Php & Ubuntu 16 Cannot Upload Large Files

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu

I am stuck and I cannot figure out why Ubuntu and PHP (Symfony3) are not allowing files larger than 2Mb to get uploaded. I have changed all of my php.ini settings and restarted apache, yet still the issue persists. Here are my settings in php.ini

When I run php -i from command line I have the following output:

```
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini (this is the .ini file I have edited)
file_uploads => On => On
max_execution_time => 0 => 0 (in my php.ini i have max_execution_time = 300 - not sure why this says 0)
max_file_uploads => 20 => 20
max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64
max_input_time => -1 => -1
max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000
memory_limit => -1 => -1
post_max_size => 64M => 64M
upload_max_filesize => 64M => 64M
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Excellent, that worked perfect!

Comment: That'd be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently changing the php.ini for CLI (PHP executed through command line), which doesn't affect PHP through Apache. You need to change the php.ini for Apache instead at:

```
/etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini
```

Change that ini-file and restart Apache and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You have already installed 2 php... you can copy your php.ini.default  from /etc directory 
the command looks like this

> sudo cp php.ini.default php.ini

After that, you can edit your php.ini file and don't forget to restart you apache first with this command

> sudo apachectl restart

and then you can check again with comman

> php -r

hope this answer will help you. thanks